# Duplicate a folder (size 150MB - 200MB) of one S3 bucket to another S3 bucket of different region using PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to copy a folder (size 150MB - 200MB) of one S3 bucket to another S3 bucket of the different region using PHP or in S3 term **"duplicate all objects with the prefix of an S3 bucket into objects with a different prefix to another S3 bucket"**

I have tried below code but it's not workings

```
$s3 = new S3Client(['credentials' => $credentials, 'version' => 'latest','region' => $region,'debug' => false ]); 
$s3->registerStreamWrapper(); 
$result = $s3->uploadDirectory("s3://{$source_bucket}/{$key}",$target_‌​bucket);
```

and I have also tried to list out all objects (using listObject function) from source bucket then copy it (Using copyObject function ) into destination bucket. But this process is consuming too much time.

Any suggestion

Comment: Have you considered using cross region replication? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cross-region-replication-for-amazon-s3/

Comment: Thanks for your response @Tim, and I found your solution is perfectly matched to my problem but I doubted, Can I select my client's bucket as a destination bucket. (Client's bucket is in eu-west-1 region and my bucket is in ap-southeast-1 region)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, you should use [Cross Region Replication](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cross-region-replication-for-amazon-s3/). You can replicate between any region you like. There's more information [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html).

**Update**
Cross region replication where source and destination buckets are owned by different accounts, [walk-through here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr-walkthrough-2.html).

Comment: While configuration I wasn't able to select destination bucket from the option "Select Bucket" under "Destination". I am wondering how can I select my Client's bucket without configuring it, or in other words,  I am not giving any access key or secret key of client's bucket. How can I access it with just selecting the bucket under "Destination" option (If i able to do)? Please elaborate this a bit more.

Comment: That's a really significant requirement you didn't include in either your question or your follow up comment. I spent 15 seconds on Google and found the answer for you, linked above.